# undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) for and action that was excuted

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

I have the following code:

```
def find_status(arg)
    10.times do
      table = table_element(:css => 'css.path')
      break if table.visible?
    end
    table = table_element(:css => 'css.path')
    if table.visible?
      table.each do |row|
        STDOUT.puts row[1].text
        match = /^#{arg}\n(String \S+) at .+/.match(row[1].text)
        return match[1] if match
      end
    end
    return "status unknown"
  end
```

Now the problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The weird part is that it prints exactly what I wanted it to print and points out that the error is on the "STDOUT" row.
So to sum it up it's executing the command but says row is a nil value.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You wanted it to print 'nil'?

Comment: I don’t want it to print nil but I would expect it to “print” nil since it’s supposedly doesn’t hold anything but instead it prints the actual information I expect it to hold.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the HTML that reproduces the issue. In particular, are you sure that every row in in the table has 2 columns?

Comment: Hey @JustinKo - that’s exactly what I was looking into... apparently one of the rows is a footer that has one column only. This issue might be solved, still tying loose ends. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, just test for nil first, then use the row text if a row exists.

```
STDOUT.puts row[1] ? row[1].text : 'nil'
```

Comment: I can do that, but if it triggers the error again but still hold information in the table then it’s just a bandaid. I can also use “begin - rescue” but I want to understand what could trigger that if it’s not actually nil.